# ignore out the version in the url and add trailing slash except for the file

Tags: regex, nginx

I have to add a trailing slash in the url  that refers to a location that doesn't correspond to an actual, individual file. For e.g:

http://example.com/Myapp/42.5.01/Mobile.zip

Here i have in the url the version of the application which has ".' for e.g 42.5.01. So when i have the below regular ex:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

This is ignoring to put the trailing slash after 42.5.01. Hence we are not able to access/download the Mobile.zip.

The Trailing slash should not be for individual file only.

The file can be a ".tar", ".war", or a ".zip"

How do i make sure the trailing slash is for the version but not for the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with a negative lookahead assertion to match some patterns but ignore other patterns. For example, to match URIs which do not end with a `/` character and ignore URIs that end with a 3 or 4 character extension, you could use:

```
rewrite "^/(?!.*\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}$).*[^/]$" $uri/ permanent;
```

The first part `(?!.*\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}$)` is a negative lookahead. See [this document](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for details.

---

Alternatively, you can use `break` in a rule to stop `rewrite` processing before your rule is reached, for example:

```
if ($uri ~ "\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}$") { break; }
rewrite "[^/]$" $uri/ permanent;
```

Or:

```
rewrite "\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}$" $uri break;
rewrite "[^/]$" $uri/ permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#break) for details.

---

Finally, depending on the structure of your configuration file, you may be able to use `location` blocks to limit the scope of the rewrite. For example:

```
location / {
    return 301 $uri/;
}
location ~ "\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}$" {
    ...
}
location ~ /$ {
    ...
}
```

The above is likely to break any non-trivial configuration as Nginx chooses a single `location` block [to process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and the presence of other `location` blocks will interfere with the logic.